# Calculating hamburger object bar position

Tags: html, css, sass

I have this hamburger I'm creating. I'm trying to understand how to position the bars with precise calculation without eyeballing it. The hamburger height is 24px 
so I would assume in order to position the middle bar it would be half the height  so 12px(top: 12px;) or incase of the example 0.5em but that doesn't look centered to the overall menu. (top: 10px looks right or 0.625em).

Overall whats a better way to calculate anything in css?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bjjqez

```
<div class="hamburger">
  <div class="hamburger__top"></div>
  <div class="hamburger__middle"></div>
  <div class="hamburger__bottom"></div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
.hamburger {
  position: relative;
  width: 3em;
  height: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  div {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: .25em;
  }
  &__top {
    top: 0;
  }
  &__middle {
    background-color: green;
    top: 0.5em;
  }
  &__bottom {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `top: 0.5em` with:

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

From my understanding of how this works, the `top: 50%` will move the top of the element to be half way down. The `translateY(-50%)` will then move the element up by half it's own height, and therefore centrally position it.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrrqWP

Comment: @Phreak see update :) - `top: 50%` will tell the **top** of the element to be   at 50% of the parent container

Comment: Okay I see. So anytime I'm centering absolutely positioned elements I should use translateY?

Comment: There are other ways of doing it such as [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but it depends on the [browsers you want to target](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), notice IE in particular

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox can do that....no positioning required.

Here's a couple of options.

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 3em;
  height: 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
.hamburger div {
  background-color: red;
  height: .25em;
}
.around {
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: lightblue;
}
.between {
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger around">
  <div class="hamburger__top"></div>
  <div class="hamburger__middle"></div>
  <div class="hamburger__bottom"></div>
</div>

<div class="hamburger between">
  <div class="hamburger__top"></div>
  <div class="hamburger__middle"></div>
  <div class="hamburger__bottom"></div>
</div>
```